# Split a bootstrap list-group-item into two columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I have a Bootstrap 3 list-group of `<a>` elements.  I would like one of them split in half so that within the group it looks similar to a button group as shown in the snippet.

How can I do this?

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item left-side">Left Side</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item right-side">Right Side</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
  </div>
  
  <p>How to divide list-group-items .left-side and .right-side so they appear on the same line but seperated similar to this:

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left Side</a>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right Side</a>
</div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: this is improper markup `ul` must contain `li` [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Comment: oops, should have been divs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class your special case so we can target the items with the correct specificity

*Notice* the `.clearfix` that will put the floats back where they should be once finished.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
}

.list-group-item.left-side,
.list-group-item.right-side {
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom-width:0px;
}

.split-items .list-group-item.left-side{
  border-top-right-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}

.split-items .list-group-item.right-side{
  border-top-left-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
  border-top-right-radius:4px;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="clearfix split-items">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item left-side">Left Side</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item right-side ">Right Side</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `float` the `a` tags?

Add `float:left` and `width:50%` to your `.list-group-item` CSS:

```
.list-group-item {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 50%;
 float: left }
```

Comment: It's not pretty - but you could also just `clear: right` on the `.list-group-item` after floating